# Is there any way to use C# to create a form for an entity for CRM 2011?

Tags: dynamics-crm-2011

There seems to be web services to create entity, fields, solution, global option set and many more within CRM 2011 SDK. However I don't see any web services to create a form for an entity.  Anyone know any back door or ways to create a forms outside of CRM 2011 using C# or VB?

Answer (score 8):

You'll have to spend some time looking at [`FormXml`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg327975.aspx) to fine-tune the look of your form(s), but you can programmatically manage your entity forms via the [`SystemForm` entity](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg334527.aspx).

> FormXml is stored in the SystemForm entity. You can programmatically
>   retrieve and update the FormXml using this entity.